# How to implement time filter to show random post 1 month for one category and 3 months for other categories

Tags: wp-query, filters, query-posts, query, wp-parse-args

I started to work on one website after another developer and there is problem with his "popular widget" which is basically showing 3 random posts from category. There is some Switch statement which is regulating to show from category news 3 random post not older then 1 month and for other categories 3 month. I don't understand what he did there with ['interval'] but when I use wordpress time parameters still I don't have results.

```
function getSomePost($category,$postsPerPage=3) {
        global $post;

        $args = array(
            'category_name'=>$category,
            'posts_per_page'=>$postsPerPage,
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID),
            'orderby'=>'rand',
        );

        switch ($category)
        {
            case 'news':
                $args['interval'] = '1 MONTH';
                break;
            case 'analysis':
                $args['interval'] = '3 MONTH';
                break;
            case 'reports':
                $args['interval'] = '3 MONTH';
                break;
        }

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
               while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
               $query->the_post();
               $postThumbClass = 'no-thumb';
               ?>
                   <div <?php post_class(array('wp-post-entry', 'sidebar-post' )); ?>>
                    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail ()):?>
                        <?php $postThumbClass = '' ?>
                        <div class="wp-post-thumbnail">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(70,70)); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                     <?php endif; ?>


                    <div class="wp-post-full-content <?php echo $postThumbClass ?> ">
                        <h3 class="wp-post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<!--
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
                        </div>
//-->
                    </div>
                </div>
               }
        }

    }
```

I was trying to replace inside switch

```
case 'news':
                $args['interval'] = '1 MONTH';
                break;
```

with

```
case 'news':
    // Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
    function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
        // posts in the last 30 days
        $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
        return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    break;
```

and

```
case 'analysis':
                    $args['interval'] = '3 MONTH';
                    break;
```

with

```
case 'analysis':
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts in the last 30 days
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
break;
```

but it is not working I tried also to use `if ($category == 'news')` but it breaks the site

Comment: You should try to move the `filter_where()` function outside of the `getSomePost()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but there is no result showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare multiple functions with same name in PHP. Codex examples for this are technical demonstration, rather than ready-made usable snippet.

Give your filter functions unique names, that are not likely to clash with your own or third party code.

Comment: I am confused what actually to change in this example.

Comment: @levat you cannot have multiple functions called `filter_where()`, name them uniquely